# php вывод файлов из двух директорий

Tags: php, javascript, html

Задача:
У меня имеются 2 папки (условно: ***"img"*** и ***"files"*** - в одной содержатся изображения, в другой файлы) и я хочу вывести (картинку и файл) в ДИВ-ы такого вида:`<div><a href="ссылка на файл(files)"><img src="ссылка на картинку (img)"></a></div>`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Мой код:

### Над html и head:

```
$category = $_GET['nesgames']; //отправка переменной через GET-запрос вида  www.site.com/nesgames=a
$url = "neser/older/$category"; //путь к папке с файлами
$temp_array = array("10", "15", "30", "50");

if (!ctype_digit($n) or !in_array($n, $temp_array)):
    $n = "15";
endif;

switch ($n):
    case 10:
        $max   = "10";
        $link1 = "<b>10</b>";
        break;
    case 15:
        $max  = "15";
        $link = "<b>15</b>";
        break;
    case 30:
        $max   = "30";
        $link2 = "<b>30</b>";
        break;
    case 50:
        $max   = "50";
        $link3 = "<b>50</b>";
        break;
endswitch;

$dir = opendir($url);
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false):
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file{0} != ""):
        $images[] = $file;
    endif;
endwhile;
closedir($dir);

if (!ctype_digit($p) or $p > $pages):
    $p = "1";
endif;
$first = ($p * $max) - $max;
$last  = ($p * $max) - 1;
```

### В месте где нужно вывести:

```
for ($i = $first; $i <= $last; $i++) {
    if (@$images[ $i ]) {
        $string = "$images[$i]";
        $string = preg_replace('/\\(.*?\\)|\\[.*?\\]|[0-9]{1,2}[:][0-9]{1,2}/s', '', $string);
        $directory = "neser/oldscreen/dandy a";    // Папка с изображениями
        $allowed_types = array("jpg", "png", "gif");  //разрешеные типы изображений
        $file_parts = array();
        $ext   = "";
        $title = "";
        $i     = 0;

        $dir_handle = @opendir($directory) or die("Ошибка, попробуйте перезагрузить страницу!"); //пробуем открыть папку

        while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) { //поиск по файлам
            if ($file == "." || $file == "..") continue; //пропустить ссылки на другие папки

            $file_parts = explode(".", $file); //разделить имя файла и поместить его в массив
            $ext        = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts)); //последний элеменет - это расширение

            if (in_array($ext, $allowed_types)) {
                print '<div class="item"><a href="http://recsgames.ru/nesgames?nesid=' . $category . '&img=' . $file . '&name=' . $images[ $i ] .
                      '" target="_blank"><img id="img-radius" style="width: 100px; height: 90px;" src="' . $directory . '/' . $file .
                      '" title="' . $images[ $i ] . '" /></a></div>';
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
closedir($dir_handle);//закрыть папку

if ($pages > 1): // если страниц больше одной
    print "";
    if ($p != $pages && $ptemp2 != ($pages - 1) && $ptemp2 != $pages): #в конец
        $nextp = " ...  <a href='#' class='first_page_link'></a>";
    else:
        $nextp = null;
    endif;
    print "<br>" . $prevp . $ptwoleft . $poneleft . '<span class="num_page_not_link"><b>' . $p . '</b></span>' . $poneright . $ptworight . $nextp;
endif;
print "</div>";
```

Сразу скажу, что код у меня очень и очень плохой т.к. я его собрал из 2-х скриптов варварским способом, (Впринципе мой код работает, но есть мега-огромное "НО", из-за него у меня глючит страница сайта, где он и находится, работает эта страница хорошо только на локальном сервере), поэтому я и пришел сюда за помощью :-) Может что-то можно вырезать или изменить?.... :-)

Comment: `В месте где нужно вывести:` - вот за это уже можете себе руки оторвать. Вы должны получить все данные там, где у вас `Над html и head:`, а потом просто выводить данные подготовленные.

Comment: Заведите отдельную табличку в БД, и храните в ней `имя файла` + `имя картинки ` и выводите циклом, в чем проблема то? Код не читаем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Архитектурно неверный подход у вас.

Высокоуровневая логика должны быть примерно такая:

```
class ImageFilePair{
    private $file; // имя файлв
    private $image; // имя изображения
    и все, необходимые поля

    public function print(){
         // вывод строки, соответствующей этой паре файл-изображение
    }
}

function readFilesFromDirectory(){
    return  "массив с именами файлов";
} 

function readImagesFromDirectory(){
    return "массив с именами файлов изображений";
}

function makePairs($files, $images);{
    return "массив объектов ImageFilePair"
}

$files = readFilesFromDirectory();
$images = readImagesFromDirectory();
$pairs = makePairs($files, $images);

foreach($pairs as $pair){
    $pair.print();
}
```